# Angular not getting data from FS.readFile with promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to use an Angular service to make a call to either use `fs.readFile` or `fs.writeFile` depending on type of button pressed in order to understand how node and angular promises interact. What I have is reading writing files, but does not send back read data, nor does it throw any errors for me to understand what has gone wrong.

```
//HTML
<button ng-click="rw('write')">WRITE FILE</button>
<button ng-click="rw('read')">READ FILE</button>


//angular
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope, RWService){
    $scope.rw = function(type){
      RWService.rw(type)
      .then(
        function(res){
          console.log('success');
      }, 
        function(err){
          console.log('error');
      })
    };
  })
  .service('RWService',['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
    this.rw = function(type){
      var promise = $http.get('./rw/' + type);
      var dfd = $q.defer();
      promise.then(
        function(successResponse){
          dfd.resolve(successResponse);
        }, 
        function(errorResponse){
          dfd.reject(errorResponse);
        }
      );
      return dfd.promise;
    };
  }]);

 //node
var fs = require('fs')
  , async = require('async')
  , Q = require('Q');

var dest = './file.txt';

var rw = {
    write: function(data){
    data = data.repeat(5);
    return Q.nfcall(fs.writeFile, dest, data);
  }
  , read: function(data){
    data = data.repeat(5);
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('inside read');
    fs.readFile(dest, 'utf8', function(err, data){
      if (err){
        deferred.reject('some error');
      }else{
        deferred.resolve(data);
      }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
};

module.exports = exports = rw;

//node server
app.get('/rw/:type', function(req, res, next){
  var type = req.params.type;
  var data = 'some text string\n';
  if (type == 'write'){
    //omitted fro brevity
  }else{
    rw.read(data)
    .then(function(response){
      return {'response': response};
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      return {'index.js error': err};
    });
  }
});
```

I structured the angular `$q` portion off of [this blog post](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angularjs-promises-from-service-to-template).

Comment: What version node are you using? I personally find Q difficult to use and promises have been native to node since 0.12.

Comment: @Andrew 4.0.0. Yeah, I'm just taking my best guess about how to do this without callbacks, using strictly promises. But I'd be open to any suggestion you have for sure! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a native Promise implementation of your code.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var dest = './file.txt';

var rw = {
    write: function(data){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            data = data.repeat(5);

            fs.writeFile(function (err, result) {
                if (err) return reject(err.message);

                return resolve(result);
            });
        });
    },
    read: function(data){
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            data = data.repeat(5);

            fs.readFile(dest, 'utf8', function(err, contents) {
                if (err) return reject(err.message);

                return resolve(contents.toString());
            });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = exports = rw;
```

[edit: I just changed the code to put `data=data.repeat(5)` inside the promise factory method. Basically, if anything CAN raise an exception, you should try to put it inside that promise function, or you again run the risk of silently killing the script again.]

A couple of comments:

Returning `deferred` is incredibly useful, but you have to be careful about how you use it. I personally only use it if the asynchronous code cannot be wrapped in a simple function (such as a class instance that creates a promise in its constructor and resolves/rejects in different child methods). In your case, probably what is happening is that the script is failing in a way that `fs.readFile()` never gets called -- and so `deferred.resolve()` and `deferred.reject()` will never be reached. In cases like this, you need to use try/catch and always call `deferred.reject()` in there as well. It is a lot of extra work that is easily avoided.

Instead, you should try to use the vanilla standard implementation of Promises as you see above.

Lastly, `Q` was a groundbreaking library that basically taught the world how to do promises in the first place, but it has not been updated in years and was never particularly feature-rich or fast. If you need more features, take a look at when.js*, kew or Bluebird (note that Bluebird claims to be the fastest, but I've personally found that to be untrue.)

(*I actually loved working with when.js and find it a bit painful using dumb native promises, but hey, standards are standards.)

---

[edit: Adding details on the Angular side of things]

So based on your comment, here is what I suspect you are also looking for. You will see that here I am using `$http.get()` as the only promise. No need to use `defer()` once you are inside a promise, so actually there is no need to even include `$q`.

I'm sorry, I've never used `service()`. Even Angular's own documentation on creating services uses the `factory()` method, so that's what I'm using here.

```
.factory('RWService',['$http', function($http){
    return {
        rw: function (type) {
            // $http returns a promise. No need to create a new one.
            return $http.get('./rw/' + type)
            .then(function (response) {
                // You can do other stuff here. Here, I am returning the
                // contents of the response. You could do other stuff as
                // well. But you could also just omit this `then()` and 
                // it would be the same as returning just the response.
                return response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                // You can do other stuff here to handle the error.
                // Here I am rethrowing the error, which is exactly the
                // same as not having a catch() statement at all.
                throw err;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

If you read the comments in the code above, you should realize that you can write the same code like this:

```
.factory('RWService',['$http', function($http){
    return {
        rw: function (type) {
            return $http.get('./rw/' + type);
        }
    };
});
```

The only difference here is that RWService.rw() will eventually resolve the entire response object rather than the response data.

The thing to keep in mind here is that you can (and absolutely should) try to recycle your promises as much as possible. Basically, all you need to know about promises is:

1. every promise has a `then` and `catch` method you can wrap your logic in;
2. every `then` and `catch` return as a new promise;
3. if you throw an exception inside any `then` or `catch`, you will be thrown straight to the next `catch`, if there is one;
4. if you return a value from any `then` or `catch`, it will be passed as the argument to the very next `then` in the chain;
5. when the chain runs out of `then`s or you throw an exception and there are no more `catch`es, the promise chain ends; and
6. `then` and `catch` are fast, but they are still asynchronous, so don't add new elements to a promise chain if you don't genuinely need them.

Comment: Hi Andrew. Thank you for this detailed description of how to structure the node portion of this script. However, my real question is how i complete the cycle `angular controller => angular service => node server route => node module => return success and read data or failure back up the chain` So I could for example display the read text in an angular view or handle an error in the UI. That is where I am really struggling.

Comment: Okay. So I am going to assume that you can see the request leaving the browser and a valid response coming back from the server. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. For example, if i log in the node module, i can print out the contents of the file

Comment: If you open up your Developer Tools in Chrome and look at the Networks panel, do you see the request leaving the browser when you click the button?

Comment: I've added some more to my answer on angular here that may be useful.

Comment: Ah yes, the request goes out, but nothing comes back

Comment: Then the problem is in your server-side code. If you have access to the server (running in a terminal window perhaps?) try adding some try/catch blocks and `console.log(err)` to spot where the problem is. Again, I suspect the problem is the promise resolve/reject never being reached because of upstream errors.